# What is the meaning of "plus (adjective) que jamais"?

Tags: sens, comparatifs

Does this phrase want to say "Tu parais plus sûr de toi que d’habitude"? Or "Tu parais plus sûr de toi que tu l’as jamais été"? I think this phrase is for emphasis, but I don’t understand it perfectly.

> - Tu parais ***plus sûr*** de toi ***que jamais***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "more than ever".

Both "*never*" and "*ever*" translate to "*jamais*" in French. It can sound weird when it's use positively like "*ever*", and it's not very casual, but it's correct. For example you can hear (or mostly read) "*A-t-on jamais vu ...*", meaning a general "*have we ever seen...*"/"has anyone ever seen...*". It's really dated though.

But "*plus ... que jamais*" is still pretty common.

Comment: So "Tu parais plus sûr de toi que tu l’as jamais été"? is the longer version of meaning the same thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said it clearly. The longer version is pretty heavy so it's not used a lot. It's also less formal, so in books they'll use the other one because it sounds better, and orally we'll often use the shortest option.

Answer (score 1):

"Tu parais plus sûr de toi que tu l’as jamais été"?
It means "more than ever"